# CSS: How to force floating blocks to have equal (100%?) height

Tags: css

Simply draw the situation:

What I have:

```
----------------------------------
XXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXX    
XXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXX
----------------------------------
```

What I would like to have:

```
----------------------------------
XXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXX
----------------------------------
```

I don't want to use `display: table-cell`, because it's not cros-browser;

I don't want to use `<table>` either (if it's possible).

I would like to LEARN: **what is the trick** of forcing floating blocks fit the contaier height ?!

---

PS:
I try this way (this LESS code is not working, **you may not pay too much attention to it**)

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

    div {
        float:left;
        width: 33.3%; /*only three of them. It's strange, but this is what works: 31%*/
        min-height: 100%; /*unfortunutely not works */
        height: 100%;
        background: red;
    }
}

<div id="container">
   <div><div>
   <div><div>
   <div class="last"><div>
</div>
```

Comment: Search Google or SO for "clearfix."

Comment: I need equal height, not clearfix  http://jsfiddle.net/TButx/67/

Comment: `display: table-cell` seems to have pretty good browser support to me:  http://caniuse.com/#search=table.  The few IE7 users out there can live with the elements being unequal heights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a pure hack-free solution, you could wrap the columns in a second container, as discussed here:

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Answer (score 2):

Check this demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/FDm9F/3/embedded/result/

If you zoom, you can see that the table's height is always 100%

**HTML**

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>        
    </tr>
</table>​
```

**CSS**

```
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
table{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
table tr td{
    width:33.3%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #F00;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    text-align:center
}​
```

Comment: Did you read the question? He specifically said he didn't want to use `<table>` elements if possible.

Comment: Check the link in my answer, then... ;-)

Comment: Have you fixed your problem?

Comment: Huh? It's not my problem. I answered the OP's question above?!

Comment: Stop arduing, `<table>` solution is shorter than Taylor's. +1 for both answers!

Answer (score 1):

Does the container has a height? If not, that may be the reason for the 100% not working.

Comment: Exactly!!!  Container DOES NOT have height. I've also noticed that's the main reason of the problem